# Python & Pandas - merging csv's based on string search

Tags: python, pandas, csv

With Python I'm seeking to create a script that compares data in two different csvs. The first csv, `filedata.csv`, contains strings of filepaths containing information on user names and user ids. The second csv, `roster.csv`, contains those same fields broken up into different columns. I would like to search through the filepath string in `filedata.csv` for matches in `roster.csv`, and then write the columns from `roster.csv` into `filedata.csv`. Below are the csv structures, and the desired output.

`filedata.csv`

```
filename
C:\johndoe_0001_paper1.doc
C:\janedoe_0002_paper2.doc
C:\johnsmith_0003_paper3.pdf
```

`roster.csv`

```
first_name, last_name, user_id
john, doe, 0001
jane, doe, 0002
john, smith, 0003
```

Desired output for `filedata.csv`:

```
filename, first_name, last_name, user_id
C:\johndoe_0001_paper1.doc, john, doe, 0001
C:\janedoe_0002_paper2.doc, jane, doe, 0002
C:\johnsmith_0003_paper3.pdf, john, smith, 0003
```

I attempted the following code with Pandas to see if I can search through the strings in `filenames.csv` for matches from `roster.csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filenames.csv')
filenames = str(df['filename'])

roster = pd.read_csv('roster.csv')
roster_last_name = str(roster['last_name'])
roster_first_name = str(roster['first_name'])
roster_user_id = str(roster['user_id'])

print(df.loc([filenames]).str.contains([roster_last_name]))
```

But get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Likewise I've tried something simpler, but with no success, as "False" is always returned:

```
if roster_last_name in filenames:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but unsure how to proceed. All suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks. While helpful for this case, future iterations of this problem won't have the data in the two csvs lining up exactly as in this case. A search through the string will be necessary.

Comment: Well I belive, the exception occurs, because you are using `.loc([filename])`, but the actual syntax is `.loc[filename]`. However, because `filename = str(df['filename'])`, `filename`is actually the string representing the series object `df.filename`, which is not a list of filenames. `df.filename` however is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
filename['user_id'] = filename['filename'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})')
new_df = filename.merge(roster, on='user_id')
```

This solution adds a column to `filename` that is the four-digit ID (as a string) extracted from the filename, and then merges rows from the two dataframes where the user id is the same.

Your solution does not work because expressions like `str(roster['last_name'])` take a series and returns one string.

Update:

The above solution assumes that the user_id column in `roster` contains strings. If they are ints, do this:

```py
filename['user_id'] = filename['filename'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})').astype(int)
new_df = filename.merge(roster, on='user_id')
```

The only difference is `.astype(int)`.

Please let me know if this is not what was wanted.

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful info. However, I'm getting an error message from Pandas indicating I should pd.concat instead of pd.merge (specifically - "ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"). What path might you suggest?

Comment: My solution assumes that the `user_id` column in each dataframe is a string, as your examples show the IDs as four-digit numbers with leading 0s. Leading 0s would not display if the values are encoded as ints. I will update my answer in a moment.

Comment: Many thanks for the assistance, and persistence through my incomplete description. All works great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

With the following (`df1` from `filenames.csv` and `df2` from `roster.csv`):

```py
for i in df1.index:
    for c in df2.columns:
        df1.loc[df1.filename.str.contains(df2.loc[i, "last_name"] and df2.loc[i, "user_id"].astype(str)), c] = df2.loc[i, c]
```

This checks for `last_name` and `user_id`, because `jane` and `john` both have `doe` as `last_name`.
This gives you the following:

```
|    | filename                     | first_name   | last_name   |   user_id |
|---:|:-----------------------------|:-------------|:------------|----------:|
|  0 | C:\johndoe_0001_paper1.doc   | john         | doe         |         1 |
|  1 | C:\janedoe_0002_paper2.doc   | jane         | doe         |         2 |
|  2 | C:\johnsmith_0003_paper3.pdf | john         | smith       |         3 |
```

Comment: Iterative solutions should be avoided in pandas as much as possible. It is possible to solve this using the `merge` method without any Python loops.